# Format string representing hours as H:MM in output

Tags: string, powershell, time, type-conversion

How do I *convert* the string representing hours to the `H:MM` format *in the same command* that outputs the result?

I have this code:

```
$RunAfterHour = 7
$DelayInMinutes = 10
$RunScriptAfterTime = $RunAfterHour + $DelayInMinutes / 60    # 7:10 AM
"It's after $RunScriptAfterTime"
```

Which returns:

```
It's after 7.166666666666667
```

But I want to format the output as time so it looks like this:

```
It's after 7:10
```

I've tried:

```
"It's after (Get-Date $RunScriptAfterTime -format 't')"
[datetime]::ParseExact($RunScriptAfterTime, 'h.mmmmmmm',$null).ToString('t')
```

And others but no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you already have the hour and minutes, you could just format it:

```
"It's after {0}:{1:D2}" -f $RunAfterHour, $DelayInMinutes
```

**Output:**

```
It's after 7:10
```

---

**Edit reflecting your comment:**

Since you only have the time in hours (`$RunScriptAfterTime`) you can use the *static* `[timespan]::FromHours` method:

```
$timespan = [timespan]::FromHours($RunScriptAfterTime)
"It's after {0}:{1:D2}" -f $timespan.Hours, $timespan.Minutes
```

Or altogether:

```
[timespan]::FromHours($RunScriptAfterTime).ToString('t')
```